# Como criar um esquema MySQL depois de iniciar uma instancia na AWS-RDS?

Tags: datatable, amazon-aws

Estou iniciando com o Relational Database Service da AWS.
Já iniciei uma instância MySQL e agora os próximos passos são:

1. Rodar o sql que cria o esquema e as tabelas,
2. Rodar o sql que insere os dados.

Como eu poderia fazer isso? Tem como conectar usando o workbench ou heidsql?

Comment: Sua instância está com acesso público? Se sim, basta configurar ip e porta no workbench. Caso sua instância só tenha acesso dentro da sua vpc, é necessário configurar a conexão via SSH utilizando sua chave de acesso (.pem). Da uma olhada: http://www.inoneo.com/en/blog/15/amazon-aws/connect-to-an-aws-rds-instance-inside-a-vpc-using-mysql-workbench

Comment: consegui. O problema é que ele estava private. Coloquei publica e consegui conectar usando workbench. Publica la sua resposta.

Comment: Publicada! Lembrando que, em produção, é uma boa ideia você manter a instância de banco como "private" (acesso somente dentro da sua vpc).

Comment: Com certeza. Em produção só vai ser acessivel pelos grupos VPC. Essa é somente teste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se sua instância está com acesso público basta configurar ip, porta, usuário e senha no Workbench. Caso sua instância só tenha acesso dentro da sua VPC, é necessário configurar a conexão via SSH utilizando sua chave de acesso(.pem).

Um tutorial que pode ajudar: http://www.inoneo.com/en/blog/15/amazon-aws/connect-to-an-aws-rds-instance-inside-a-vpc-using-mysql-workbench